# Tried boost::mpi::environment::processor_name(), get ld error

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, mpi, ld

test.cpp:

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <string>
int main(void) {
    std::string s = boost::mpi::environment::processor_name();
    //std::cout << boost::mpi::environment::processor_name << "\n";
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(test CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) # require C++14
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS mpi REQUIRED)
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
        test
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Error (g++ 6 and cmake):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::mpi::environment::processor_name[abi:cxx11]()", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Why the error?

By the way, when I use the commented out line `std::cout << boost::mpi::environment::processor_name << "\n";`, the program compiles and print out `1`.

[Here](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/doxygen/boost/classboost_1_1mpi_1_1environment.html#a76936cda9ab261e05730df0ccdde9502) is the documentation on the processor_name function.

Comment: It is definitely something wrong with the cmake file. I tried the code at here, which doesn't use any cmake file and that works fine. https://particlephysicsandcode.wordpress.com/tag/install-boost-mpi/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write CMakeLists.txt for boost::mpi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768921/write-cmakelists-txt-for-boostmpi)